# Which weapons can be upgraded in Darksiders 2?

Tags: darksiders-2

I know I can upgrade possessed weapons but what about the rest of the weapons in the game? Can I upgrade armor too or just weapons?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't upgrade any other gear except possessed weapons. The way to 'upgrade' armor is to replace your current items with better ones, that fit your play-style and talents, as you progress through the game.